# How to show to the hypothesis is equivalent to ZL

Tags: order-theory

The following is from A Book of Set Theory
by Pinter. Chapter 5, Ex. 5.4.4

5.14 Theorem (Hausdorff’s Maximal Principle). Every partially ordered set has a maximal chain.

5.15 Definition A partially ordered set A is said to be inductive if every chain of A has an upper bound in A.

5.16 Theorem (Zorn’s Lemma). Every inductive set has at least one maximal element

Prove that Zorn’s Lemma is equivalent to the following: Let A be an inductive set and let a ∈ A; then A has at least one maximal element b such that b>=a

Attempted proof:
(caveat lector: my proof proof will sound
Gobbledygook gook)

Assume the hypothesis:
By 5.24 and Def 5.15
let C be a maximal chain in A.Let a be an upper bound in A. Let D be a chain in C

K=$\bigcup D$ for D $\in C$

So K is the l.u.b If a,b$\in $ K then a $\in$ N and b $\in$ M for M,N$\in$ C .By assumption
aa so K is totally ordered .So
a<=b

By our hypothesis b is maximal . C is a chain,we have the upper bound a $\in $ A Then  C $\cup$ {a} is a chain. So by the maximality  of C a $\in $ C .

If b>a then
C $\cup$ {b} is a totally ordered set. So b$\in$ C; a$\le$ b then a=b.
Therefore hypothesis =>ZL is shown.

I hope I got this part correct
Any help appreciated.
My knowledge of working with ZL is shaky

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit this post using MathJax (it's easy; a guide is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). You've already done a nice job fleshing out your question and showing your work; this last step will make it a fine question.

Comment: I fixed it up. I find it long winded. Don’t know how to apply the KISS principle to it